# Python - Tkinter not support MacOS Mojave Dark Mode

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit, macos-darkmode

I have a problem with the support of Dark Mode on MacOS in python Tkinter.
I used *python 3.6 with ActiveTlc 8.5* and the Dark Mode works fine, the window titlebar was dark, it's fine for me... but there were some problems with the `<MouseWheel>` support, then I **upgraded** *python to 3.7.1* and the version of *tlc* is updated to *8.6*.

But now the *Dark Mode* didn't work, and it's strange, why this is happening?

This is an example code:

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    hero_text = Label(root, fg='white', bg='black', text='HERO TEXT')
    hero_text.grid(row=0, sticky=N+W)
    print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))
    print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're lucky it's just the dark mode. On my system TK applications just show empty, black windows. I would recommend switching to a more modern toolkit like GTK+ 3 or Qt 4.

Comment: @Bachsau This issue has been fixed in 8.6.9 according to tk developers https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=821dbe47e1

Comment: This post can help if someone on Mac wants Mojave Dark Mode on Tkinter applications https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483507/how-to-get-a-black-file-dialog-box-using-tkinter-on-mac-os

Comment: You can fix this issue by installing the newest python.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this kind of problem, I think you should try this

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
       root = Tk()
       root.configure(bg="black")
       hero_text = Label(root, fg='white', bg='black', text='HERO TEXT')
       hero_text.grid(row=0, sticky=N+W)
       print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))
       print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))
       root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the base tkinter module, there is no way to automate dark mode without another module like subprocess. I recommend you add a setting for dark mode, but if you want it to still be automated here is the code to do it:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

def check_appearance():
   cmd = 'defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle'
   p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   if bool(p.communicate()[0]):
      return "black"
   else:
      return "white"


win = Tk()
win.configure(bg=check_appearamce())

win.mainloop()
```